Find the direction of the electromagnetic fields in a frame where $A_0$ is chosen to be $0$
Let the four potential which depends on four product $\phi=kx$ be $A^\mu=A^\mu(\phi).$ In one section of the Landau and Lifshitz QED book, the authors chose a reference frame where $A_0=0,$ $\vec{A}$ is in the direction $x^1$ axis and $\vec{k}$ is along $x^3$ direction. Now they claim that the electric field is along $x^1$ axis and the magnetic field is along $x^2$ axis.
I have attempted to understand this with Maxwell's equation. Lets say we want to find the direction of the electric field and magnetic field:
$$\vec{E}=-\nabla A^0 -\dfrac{\partial \vec{A}}{\partial x^0}=-k_0 \dfrac{d\vec{A}}{d\phi}$$
$$\vec{B}=\nabla \times \vec{A}.$$
Neither of the above seems to be at a specific direction.

@Frobenius I am studying part 40 (D.M. Volkov's solution) of chapter IV (particles in an external field) where equation (40.1) says $A^\mu=A^\mu(\phi)$ and equation (40.2) says $kA=0$.

@Frobenius Sure they are the same, except a minor difference of mostly minus convention that the book uses but it seems you are writing mostly plus in 101.19b. But I am still not sure how can I use these to figure out the direction of the electric and magnetic fields. I assumed that applying Maxwell's equations may help as I wrote in the question but to no avail. $a^\mu$ you wrote is still the scalar and vector potential right?

@Frobenius In your first comment you mention $F_{\mu \nu}=k_\mu a_\nu-k_\nu a_mu =$ constant. In the book, (40.13) says $F_{\mu \nu} =k_\mu A'\nu-k\nu A'_\mu$, where the primes indicate derivative wrto $\phi$; I don't see very clearly why this should be a constant.

I have missed $\phi$ in your first comment in $A^\mu= a^\mu \phi$; if this is true, it won't be hard to prove this but what is the justification behind  $A^\mu$ having this form?

$\newcommand{\bl}[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}} 
\newcommand{\e}{\bl=}
\newcommand{\p}{\bl+}
\newcommand{\m}{\bl-}
\newcommand{\mb}[1]{\mathbf {#1}}
\newcommand{\mr}[1]{\mathrm {#1}}
\newcommand{\mf}[1]{\mathfrak{#1}}
\newcommand{\plr}[1]{\left(#1\right)}
\newcommand{\clr}[1]{\left\{#1\right\}}
\newcommand{\Vlr}[1]{\left\Vert#1\right\Vert}
\newcommand{\vp}{\vphantom{\dfrac{a}{b}}}
\newcommand{\hp}[1]{\hphantom{#1}} 
\newcommand{\tl}[1]{\tag{#1}\label{#1}}$
Reference :$^{\prime\prime}$ Quantum Electrodynamics $^{\prime\prime}$
by V.B.Beresstetskii, E.M.Lifshitz and L.P.Pitaevskii
-Landau and Lifshitz Course of Theoretical Physics, Volume 4 2nd Edition 1982-
$\bl\S40.$ An electron in the field of an electromagnetic plane Wave
$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$
In above Reference we read :

Dirac's equation can be solved exactly for an electron moving in the field of an
electromagnetic plane wave (D. M. Volkov, 1937). The field of a plane wave with wave 4-vector $\:k\:$ ($k^2\e 0$) depends on the
4-coordinates only in the combination $\:\phi\e k\,x$, so that the 4-potential is
\begin{equation}
A^\mu\e A^\mu\plr{\phi},
\tl{40.1}
\end{equation}
and satisfies the Lorenz gauge condition
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu A^\mu \e  k_\mu A^{\mu\,\prime}\e 0,
\nonumber
\end{equation}
the prime denoting differentiation with respect to $\:\phi$.

Later in the same paragraph we read :

...The significance of the components of the 4-vector $\:p$, when the field is present, is more clearly seen in a particular frame of reference chosen so that $A_0 \e 0$. Let the vector $\:\mb A\:$ in this frame be along the $\:x^1\m$axis
and $\:\mb k\:$ along the $\:x^3\m$axis; the electric field of the wave is then along $\:x^1\:$ the magnetic field along $\:x^2$, and the wave itself is propagated along $\:x^3$. Then...

The OP's question is how to derive the  directions of the electric field, the magnetic field and the wave propagation given above.
$\bl{=\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!==\!=\!=\!=}$
Given that in the textbook a 4-metric with signature $\plr{\p\m\m\m}$ is used, we have the following 4-vectors :
\begin{equation}
x^\mu \e \plr{x^0,\mb x}\e \plr{x^0,x^1,x^2,x^3} \qquad x_\mu \e \plr{x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3}\e\plr{x^0,\m\mb x}
\tl{C-01}
\end{equation}
is the 4-position-vector. Note that with $\:c\e 1\:$ we have $\:x_0\e x^0 \e t$.
\begin{equation}
k^\mu \e \plr{k^0,\mb k}\e \plr{k^0,k^1,k^2,k^3} \qquad k_\mu \e \plr{k_0,k_1,k_2,k_3}\e\plr{k^0,\m\mb k}
\tl{C-02}
\end{equation}
is the wave 4-vector. This 4-vector is a light-like (null) vector
\begin{equation}
k^2\e k_\mu k^\mu\e k^2_0\m \Vlr{\mb k}^2\e 0
\tl{C-03}
\end{equation}
Note that with $\:c\e 1\:$
\begin{equation}
\omega \e k_0 \e \ k^0 \e \Vlr{\mb k}
\tl{C-04}
\end{equation}
is the wave angular frequency  by convention non-negative.
\begin{equation}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!A^\mu \e \plr{A^0,\mb A}\e \plr{A^0,A^1,A^2,A^3} \qquad A_\mu \e \plr{A_0,A_1,A_2,A_3}\e\plr{A^0,\m\mb A}
\tl{C-05}
\end{equation}
is the 4-potential-vector.
We have also the following scalar
\begin{equation}
\phi \e k_\mu x^\mu \e k_0x^0\p k_1x^1\p k_2x^2\p k_3x^3 \e k_0x_0 \m \mb k\bl\cdot\mb x \e \omega t\m\mb k\bl\cdot\mb x
\tl{C-06}
\end{equation}
the phase of the plane wave. Note that the phase $\:\phi\:$ is a Lorentz-invariant scalar as the inner product of two 4-vectors in Minkwoski 4-dimensional space.
We consider here an electromagnetic plane wave so that the 4-potential is a function of the phase $\:\phi\:$ as by equation \eqref{40.1} of the textbook
\begin{equation}
A^\mu\e A^\mu\plr{\phi}
\tl{C-07}
\end{equation}
which satisfies the Lorenz gauge condition
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu A^\mu \e 0
\tl{C-08}
\end{equation}
From \eqref{C-08}
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu A^\mu \e \dfrac{\mr d A^\mu}{\mr d\phi}\partial_\mu \phi\e \dfrac{\mr d A^\mu}{\mr d\phi}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^\mu}\e \dfrac{\mr d A^\mu}{\mr d\phi}k_\mu
\tl{C-09}
\end{equation}
We define the following 4-vector
\begin{equation}
a^\mu\plr{\phi}\stackrel{\texttt{def}}{\bl\equiv} \dfrac{\mr d A^\mu\plr{\phi}}{\mr d\phi}\e \plr{\dfrac{\mr d A^0}{\mr d\phi},\dfrac{\mr d\mb A}{\mr d\phi}}\e \plr{a^0, \mb a}\e \plr{a^0, a^1,a^2,a^3}
\tl{C-10}
\end{equation}
the derivative of the 4-potential with respect to the phase $\:\phi$. This is a 4-vector as the ratio of the differential 4-vector $\:\mr d A^\mu\:$ and the differential Lorentz-invariant scalar $\:\mr d \phi$. It depends on the 4-coordinates as the 4-potential $\:A^\mu$(Note : in the textbook the notation $\:A^{\mu\,\prime}\:$ is used for $\:a^\mu$).
From \eqref{C-10} we have
\begin{equation}
a_\mu\plr{\phi}\e \dfrac{\mr d A_\mu\plr{\phi}}{\mr d\phi}\e \plr{\dfrac{\mr d A_0}{\mr d\phi},\m\dfrac{\mr d\mb A}{\mr d\phi}}\e \plr{a_0, \m\mb a}\e \plr{a_0, a_1,a_2,a_3}
\tl{C-11}
\end{equation}
The Lorenz gauge condition \eqref{C-08} by equation \eqref{C-09} and the definition \eqref{C-10} yields
\begin{equation}
\partial_\mu A^\mu \e k_\mu a^\mu \e k_0 a_0\m \mb a\bl\cdot\mb k \e  0
\tl{C-12}
\end{equation}
We'll determine now the electric $\:\mb E\:$ and magnetic $\:\mb B\:$ field for the given 4-potential in equations \eqref{C-07},\eqref{C-08}.
The electromagnetic field tensor is
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!\!F_{\mu\nu}
\e & \quad\partial_\mu A_\nu\m\partial_\nu A_\mu \\
\e & 
\begin{bmatrix}
\plr{\partial_0 A_0\m\partial_0 A_0}&\plr{\partial_0 A_1\m\partial_1 A_0}&\plr{\partial_0 A_2\m\partial_2 A_0}&\plr{\partial_0 A_3\m\partial_3 A_0}\vp\\
 \plr{\partial_1 A_0\m\partial_0 A_1}&\plr{\partial_1 A_1\m\partial_1 A_1}&\plr{\partial_1 A_2\m\partial_2 A_1}&\plr{\partial_1 A_3\m\partial_3 A_1}\vp \\
 \plr{\partial_2 A_0\m\partial_0 A_2} &\plr{\partial_2 A_1\m\partial_1 A_2}&\plr{\partial_2 A_2\m\partial_2 A_2}&\plr{\partial_2 A_3\m\partial_3 A_2}\vp \\
 \plr{\partial_3 A_0\m\partial_0 A_3} &\plr{\partial_3 A_1\m\partial_1 A_3}&\plr{\partial_3 A_2\m\partial_2 A_3}&\plr{\partial_3 A_3\m\partial_3 A_3}\vp
 \end{bmatrix}\\
\e & 
\begin{bmatrix}
 \hp\m 0 & \hp\m E_1  & \hp\m E_2  & \hp\m E_3  \:\:\vp \\
 \m E_1  & \hp\m 0    & \m B_3    & \hp\m B_2 \:\:\vp \\
 \m E_2  & \hp\m B_3 & \hp\m 0    & \m B_1    \:\:\vp \\
 \m E_3  & \m B_2    & \hp\m B_1 & \hp\m 0    \:\:\vp
 \end{bmatrix}\\
\end{split}
\tl{C-13}
\end{equation}
So
\begin{equation}
E_j \e \partial_0 A_j\m\partial_j A_0\,,\quad j\e 1,2,3 
\tl{C-14}
\end{equation}
Above equation is the tensorial version of the Maxwell's 3-vector equation
\begin{equation}
\mb E \e \m \dfrac{\partial \mb A}{\partial t}\m \bl\nabla A_0
\tl{C-15}
\end{equation}
Now
\begin{equation}
\partial_0 A_j \e \dfrac{\mr d A_j}{\mr d \phi}\partial_0 \phi \e \dfrac{\mr d A_j}{\mr d \phi}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^0 }\e a_j k_0 \e \m k_0 a^j
\tl{C-16}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
\partial_j A_0 \e \dfrac{\mr d A_0}{\mr d \phi}\partial_j \phi \e \dfrac{\mr d A_0}{\mr d \phi}\dfrac{\partial \phi}{\partial x^j }\e a_0 k_j \e \m a_0 k^j
\tl{C-17}
\end{equation}
From equations \eqref{C-14},\eqref{C-16} and \eqref{C-17} we have
\begin{equation}
E_j \e a_0 k^j \m  k_0 a^j\,,\quad j\e 1,2,3 
\tl{C-18}
\end{equation}
so
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
\mb E \e a_0 \mb k \m  k_0 \mb a\:\:\vp}
\tl{C-19}
\end{equation}
For the magnetic field
\begin{equation}
\mb B \e
\begin{bmatrix}
B_1\vp\\
B_2\vp\\
B_3\vp
\end{bmatrix}
\e
\begin{bmatrix}
\partial_3 A_2\m\partial_2 A_3\vp\\
\partial_1 A_3\m\partial_3 A_1\vp\\
\partial_2 A_1\m\partial_1 A_2\vp
\end{bmatrix}
\e
\begin{bmatrix}
 a_2 k^3\m a_3 k^2\vp\\
 a_3 k^1\m a_1 k^3\vp\\
 a_1 k^2\m a_2 k^1\vp
\end{bmatrix}
\e
\begin{bmatrix}
 a^3 k^2 \m a^2 k^3 \vp\\
 a^1 k^3 \m a^3 k^1 \vp\\
 a_2 k^1 \m a_1 k^2\vp
\end{bmatrix}
\tl{C-20}
\end{equation}
that is
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:\mb B \e \mb k \bl\times \mb a\:\:\vp} 
\tl{C-21}
\end{equation}
The 3-vectors $\:\mb k\:$ and $\:\mb a\:$ are not orthogonal in general. But in a frame with $\:A_0 \e 0\:$ we have also $\:a_0 \e 0\:$ and the Lorenz gauge condition \eqref{C-12} yields orthogonal 3-vectors $\:\mb k\:$ and $\:\mb a$ :
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
A_0\e 0 \bl\implies a_0\e 0  \bl\implies  \mb a\bl\cdot\mb k \e  0\:\:\vp}
\tl{C-22}
\end{equation}
On the other hand with  $\:a_0 \e 0\:$ equation \eqref{C-19} yields
\begin{equation}
\boxed{\:\:
A_0\e 0 \bl\implies a_0\e 0  \bl\implies  \mb E \e \m k_0 \mb a\:\:\vp}
\tl{C-23}
\end{equation}
So in case of a frame with $\:A_0 \e 0\:$ the set of 3-vectors $\:\clr{\mb a,\mb k \bl\times \mb a,\mb k} \:$ or equivalently $\:\clr{\mb E,\mb B,\mb k} \:$ is a 3-dimensional complete orthogonal system. Taking $\:\mb E\:$ along the $\:x^1\m$axis and $\:\mb k\:$ along the $\:x^3\m$axis the magnetic field $\:\mb B\:$ will be along the $\:x^2\m$axis.
